# Update two divs with one AJAX response

Tags: php, ajax, json, jquery

All,
I'm using jQuery/AJAX to call a file to basically save it someone likes a song or not. I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
var html = $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "save_song.php",
data: "song_id=" + song_id + "&love_like_hate=hate",
async: false
}).responseText;

$("#div_song_id_"+song_id).html(responseText1);
$("#love_it").html(responseText2);
```

Then on the PHP side have something like this:

```
echo "This text would go in response text 1";
echo "This text would go in response text 2";
```

So basically I'm trying to have multiple echo's in the save_song.php file and then basically say the first echo goes to the first div and the second echo goes to the second div that needs updated. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PHP code could give back a JSON string:

```
<?php
    echo json_encode(array(
        'test1' => 'This text would go in response text 1',
        'test2' => 'This text would go in response text 2'
    ));
?>
```

Then you can parse it in jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "save_song.php",
    data: "song_id=" + song_id + "&love_like_hate=hate",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(response) {
        if (response && response.text1 && response.text2) {
            $("#div_song_id_"+song_id).html(response.text1);
            $("#love_it").html(response.text2);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I would do this with json. If you echo out an associative array in your php and json encode it, jQuery will automatically convert the json string into an object.

Alternatively you could echo out the two statements with some kind of delimiter (like `|&*etc...`) and then split it with javascript, but I think this is a cleaner way to do it.

```
//php
echo json_encode(array(
    "responseText1" : "This text would go in response text 1",
    "responseText2" : "This text would go in response text 2"
))

//javascript
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "save_song.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "song_id=" + song_id + "&love_like_hate=hate",
    success:function(val){
        $("#div_song_id_"+song_id).html(val.responseText1);
        $("#love_it").html(val.responseText2);

    }
});
```

Comment: +1 json is definitely the way how to do this. I would also add site with little more detailed explanation and examples like this http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/ (2nd block, first working page after googling "jquery ajax json example")

Comment: Nice thanks, don't really know any good ajax. Thanks for the link

Comment: @locrizak Thanks for the code. I tried to do this but when I try and do an alert(val.responseText1) it says that it is undefined. Any idea why this would be the case?

Comment: try console.log(val) and try to debug it that way. If it still doesn't work then there might be a problem with how you are echoing it our on the php side