# How to use json_encode with mix of html and php outside PHP tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I want to update two divs with one ajax call with json encode outside php marks.
I am familiar with  [Update two divs with one AJAX response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988188/update-two-divs-with-one-ajax-response) but would it be possible to do something similar but with data **outside** < php ?>

Instead of echo-ing ajax response i've closed php and used regular html like for example here is code server side:

```
<?php
//here some code that cheks some stuff
var $somvariable="Ipsum";
?>
<p>Lorem Lorem <?php echo $somvariable ; ?></p>
```

and then in ajax function I update div like:

```
success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
{
//data: return data from server
$('#divid').html(data);
}
```

Now imagine i have to use json_encode to create two variables that update two divs so i can do:

```
success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
{
$('#dividone').html(data.one);
$('#dividtwo').html(data.two);
}
```

and my code outside < ?php ?> is to big and would be too time consuming to convert it to normal string.
How can I make this work? My guess is use raw json but how?
obviously nothing like:

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array(
    'one' => '?><p>Lorem Lorem <?php echo $somvariable ; ?></p><?php',
    'two' => '?><p>Lorem <?php echo $somvariable2 ; ?></p><?php'
));
?>
```

Will not work but I hope it shows what i try to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some research I've managed to figure this out.
[ob_get_clean()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) and [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) is what I needed.

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<div>First huge mix of php and html goes <?php echo "here"; ?></div>
<?php $one= ob_get_clean(); 
ob_start(); ?>
<div>Second huge mix of php and html goes <?php echo "here"; ?></div>
<?php $two= ob_get_clean();
echo json_encode(array(
  'one' => $one,
  'two' => $two
)); ?>
```

and in ajax I used

```
success:function(data) 
{
$('#dividone').html(data.one);
$('#dividtwo').html(data.two);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

may be you need to set header in php

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

so your php code should be something like this

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array(
    'one' => '<p>Lorem Lorem '.$somvariable.'</p>',
    'two' => '<p>Lorem  '.$somvariable2.'</p>'
));
?>
```

and in ajax use

```
success:function(data) 
{
   $('#dividone').html(data.one);
   $('#dividtwo').html(data.two);
}
```

Comment: That is interesting - could you provide example of simple json with two variables created this way? 
so something like <?php header('Content-Type: application/json'); ?> and then how to format variables?

Comment: @GrzegorzZieliński I actually use it in my code in this way .. but I don't have a live example to it .. just replace it with your code and test it .. and see updated answer

Comment: The problem is <p>Lorem Lorem <?php echo $somvariable ; ?></p> really is a much bigger html / php code. Thats why it would be time consuming to convert it to normal php string like in your response. That's why I'm trying to find a way to do it outside php - perhaps in raw json.